# Using Basic HTTP access authentication in Django testing framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http-authentication, django-testing

For some of my Django views I've created a decorator that performs Basic HTTP access authentication.  However, while writing test cases in Django, it took me a while to work out how to authenticate to the view.  Here's how I did it. I hope somebody finds this useful.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
from django.test import Client
import base64
auth_headers = {
    'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('username:password'),
}
c = Client()
response = c.get('/my-protected-url/', **auth_headers)
```

Note: You will also need to create a user.

Comment: If you are manipulation unicode strings (typical eg: using py3)  you'd need to do something like `base64.b64encode('username:password'.encode()).decode()` because base64 module do not handle unicode strings.

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande more like `base64.b64encode(bytes('username:password', 'utf8')).decode('utf8'),`

Comment: @vyscond up to your taste, because it's strictly the same processing.

Comment: Great answer! Just complementing: Using python 3.5 I just made `c.get('/my-protected-url/', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic username:password')` as shown in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) and [CGI docs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00#section-5).

Comment: Why HTTP_AUTHORIZATION and not Authorization ?

Comment: @DanielGomezRico: Confusing, indeed. A bit late, but there's an explanation to be found in https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113248

Comment: The process for creating a valid Basic auth header, including the Base64 encoding, is described in [RFC7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617#page-5).

Comment: Same structure will work for token authorization also, just replace basic with Token

Answer (score 34):

In your Django TestCase you can update the client defaults to contain your HTTP basic auth credentials.

```
import base64
from django.test import TestCase

class TestMyStuff(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        credentials = base64.b64encode('username:password')
        self.client.defaults['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + credentials
```

Comment: This can also be done a bit more succinctly using the `credentials()` method of the `Client` object: `self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic ' + credentials)` (cf. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs).

Comment: @KurtPeek that only works with django-rest-framework, not with the vanilla Django test client

Answer (score 8):

For python3, you can base64-encode your `username:password` string:

```
base64.b64encode(b'username:password')
```

This returns bytes, so you need to transfer it into an ASCII string with `.decode('ascii')`:

Complete example:

```
import base64

from django.test import TestCase

class TestClass(TestCase):
   def test_authorized(self):
       headers = {
           'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic ' + 
                base64.b64encode(b'username:password').decode("ascii")
       }
       response = self.client.get('/', **headers)
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's so helpful .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I have a login form, I use the following technique to login through the test framework:

```
    client = Client()
    client.post('/login/', {'username': 'john.smith', 'password': 'secret'})
```

I then carry the `client` around in my other tests since it's already authenticated.  What is your question to this post?

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice solution Thierry.  Although it does not work for HTTP Authorization as that works by sending the login creditials as HTTP headers.  I'm doing it this way because the view is an API call rather than a regular view.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (for browser views). Even more straightforward: [Django client login method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login)

Answer (score 2):

(python3) I'm using this in a test:

```
credentials_string = '%s:%s' % ('invalid', 'invalid')
credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials_string.encode())
self.client.defaults['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + credentials.decode()
```

and the following in a view:

```
import base64
[...]
type, auth = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ', 1)
auth = base64.b64decode(auth.strip()).decode()
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it is to bypass the Django Client() and use Requests instead.

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        AUTH = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")

    def some_test(self):
        resp = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'endpoint/', auth=AUTH)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: the response class from `requests` is not guaranteed to be 100% compatible with the one that django uses. For example, you won't have `response.context` available.

Comment: This makes an actual http request across the network. This is almost never what you want to do in a unit test.