# Django test client http basic auth for post request

Tags: django, unit-testing

everyone. I am trying to write tests for RESTful API implemented using django-tastypie with http basic auth. So, I have the following code:

```
def http_auth(username, password):
    credentials = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).strip()
    auth_string = 'Basic %s' % credentials
    return auth_string

class FileApiTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['test/fixtures/test_users.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.extra = {
            'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': http_auth('testuser', 'qwerty')
        }

    def test_folder_resource(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/1.0/folder/', **self.extra)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_folder_resource_post(self):
        response = self.client.post('/api/1.0/folder/', **self.extra)
        self.assertNotEqual(response.status_code, 401)
```

GET request is done well, returning status code 200. But POST request always returns 401. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe check your Meta: authorization on your resource?  What does it say?

Comment: `authorization = DjangoAuthorization()`

Comment: aw, crap, I meant "Authentication" That's what you're testing here.  THe difference is Authentication == "Who are you", Authorization == "Can you do this?"

Comment: `authentication = BasicAuthentication(realm=settings.SOCIAL_API_REALM)`

Answer (score 7):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495452/using-basic-http-access-authentication-in-django-testing-framework).  I've used that code for tests using both GET and POST and it worked.  The only difference I can see is that you have used base64.encodestring instead of base64.b64encode.

Otherwise, if that doesn't work, how are you performing the HTTP Authentication?  I wrote and use this function decorator:

```
import base64
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def http_auth(view, request, realm="", must_be='', *args, **kwargs):
    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
        auth = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split()
        if len(auth) == 2:
            if auth[0].lower() == "basic":
                uname, passwd = base64.b64decode(auth[1]).split(':')
                if must_be in ('', uname):
                    user = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
                    if user is not None and user.is_active:
                            login(request, user)
                            request.user = user
                            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # They mustn't be logged in
    response = HttpResponse('Failed')
    response.status_code = 401
    response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="%s"' % realm
    return response


def http_auth_required(realm="", must_be=''):
    """ Decorator that requires HTTP Basic authentication, eg API views. """
    def view_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return http_auth(func, request, realm, must_be, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return view_decorator
```

Comment: I use django-tastypie, it has built-in bash http authentication and it works fine. I can't only make post requests with django test client and i have no idea where problem is

Comment: This file seems to handle the authentication. Have a look through it and see if you can trace what is going wrong?
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py

Answer (score 1):

I've found a reason of my problem. DjangoAuthorization checks permissions with django premissions framework, since I don't use it in my project — all post/put/delete requests from non superuser are unauthorized. My bad.

Anyway, thanks a lot to you, guys, for responses.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3

```
@staticmethod
def http_auth(username, password):
    """
    Encode Basic Auth username:password.
    :param username:
    :param password:
    :return String:
    """
    data = f"{username}:{password}"
    credentials = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8")).strip()
    auth_string = f'Basic {credentials.decode("utf-8")}'
    return auth_string


def post_json(self, url_name: AnyStr, url_kwargs: Dict, data: Dict):
    """
    Offers a shortcut alternative to doing this manually each time
    """
    header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': self.http_auth('username', 'password')}
    return self.post(
        reverse(url_name, kwargs=url_kwargs),
        json.dumps(data),
        content_type="application/json",
        **header
    )
```