# Django TokenAuthentication missing the 'Authorization' http header

Tags: django, authorization, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I'm trying to use the TokenAuthentication with one of my views.
As documented in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/, I add the token I received from the login as an HTTP header called: 'Authorization' in the request I send.

The problem is that in my unittests the authentication fails.
Looking into the TokenAuthentication class I see that the header being checked is 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' and not 'Authorization'

The view I'm using:

```
class DeviceCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Device
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Changing the header to 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' seems to work, but something feels wrong.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Looking into the TokenAuthentication class I see that the header being checked is 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' and not 'Authorization'

Not quite true, when doing lookups in the request `META` dict, the headers that it's actually looking for are with out the preceeding `HTTP_`, so `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '')` *is* actually looking up the `Authorization` header in the request.

> The problem is that in my unittests the authentication fails
>   Changing the header to 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' seems to work

I havn't double checked how the test client looks but I believe that setting `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` is what you need to do get the equivalent of actually setting the `Authorization` header.  If you actually made an http request you should find that setting the auth header works exactly as you'd expect.

See `request.META` documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

**Edit**:

Django docs on looking up headers in `request.META`:

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above,
>   any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by
>   converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with
>   underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a
>   header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

Django docs on setting headers with the test client:

> However, you can use keywords arguments to specify some default headers. For example, this will send a `User-Agent` HTTP header in each request:
>
> > > c = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')

Answer (score 8):

[Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114464/1528682) is fine, but not complete.

Your code can work fine in dev environnement (with `runserver`) but if you try it in a WSGI server (Apache in my case), the server can strip out the Authorization header !

You can find on [Boone's Blog](http://blog.goosecreekapps.com/2012/03/08/using-http-basic-authentication-with-django-on-apache/) a good fix for your Apache conf to keep the Authorization header in the request and make it work great:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: link to blog is dead, but that tip saved my sanity. didn't know Apache/WSGI was stripping headers!

Comment: This saved me as well! Apache was striping out the Authorization header!!