# Specifying basic authentication credentials for a Django REST framework API client

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run some tests to go with the Django REST tutorial (see [source code](https://github.com/encode/rest-framework-tutorial)). I got a solution working using the `APIClient`'s `.force_authenticate` method, but I'd prefer to construct the credentials more explicitly. I've tried the following:

```
import json
import base64

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, force_authenticate

from snippets.models import Snippet

class SnippetTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'john_doe'
        self.password = 'foobar'
        self.user = User.objects.create(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        # self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

        credentials = base64.b64encode(f'{self.username}:{self.password}'.encode('utf-8'))
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic {}'.format(credentials))

    def test_1(self):
        response = self.client.post('/snippets/', {'code': 'Foo Bar'}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

This test passed with the commented-out line with `.force_authenticate`, but fails in its current form, which I based on [Using Basic HTTP access authentication in Django testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495452/using-basic-http-access-authentication-in-django-testing-framework):

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:rest-framework-tutorial kurtpeek$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_1 (tutorial.tests.SnippetTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/source/rest-framework-tutorial/tutorial/tests.py", line 23, in test_1
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 403 != 201

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.022s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Apparently, the authentication is not working because I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You are doing it right. But are you sure that the header is "Basic ..."? Can you post your authentication class?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic {}'.format(credentials.decode('utf-8'))
```

Alternatively, you may also consider [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#headers-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by simply calling the `self.client`'s `login` method with the `username` and `password` of the `self.user` defined in the `setUp` method:

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from snippets.models import Snippet

class SnippetTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'john_doe'
        self.password = 'foobar'
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.username, password=self.password)

    def test_1(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        response = self.client.post('/snippets/', {'code': 'Foo Bar'}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

This test passes:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:rest-framework-tutorial kurtpeek$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.259s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```